# response saving "undefined" in my file node.js

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I know that node.js uses asynchronous behaviour. and the reason I am trying to save the response in my file system is coming to be "undefined". actually, until the response comes, the file is saved with "undefined" data.

this is my code

```
 request(options, function (error, response, body){
 if(!error){
    console.log(body);       //gives the response successfully
     fs.writeFile("E:/FirebaseNotif/testfile", body.notification_key,  function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");     //saves but with an "undefined" data
});         
 }else{
    console.log('this is false');
 }

 });
```

How to handle this kind of asynchronous behaviour

Comment: you can try to verify the function work correctly or not by creating "message.txt" in project's root and changing the `path` to `"message.txt"`, then check if it could write data in message.txt

Answer (score 1):

The issue request returns a response in a string so body variable contains string value, not JSON. You need to cast the response in JSON and use the variables

Try following after receving response

```
console.log(body);
const data = JSON.parse(body);
fs.writeFile('testfile', data.notification_key, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log('The file was saved!');
});
```